# printed value for high numbers is wronger than it should?

Tags: r, floating-point

When printing a high number in R I expect to see a rounded value due to floating point magic. Indeed :

```r
options(scipen = 999)
x <- 10000000000000000000000000
x
#> [1]  9999999999999998758486016
```

However I expected that this rounded number would be rounded to itself, and it appears it isn't

```
x ==  9999999999999998758486016
#> [1] FALSE

9999999999999998758486016
#> [1]  9999999999999996611002368
```

I found manually the min number that rounds to the original rounded value

```
x ==  9999999999999998799999999
#> [1] FALSE

9999999999999998799999999
#> [1]  9999999999999996611002368

x ==  9999999999999998800000000
#> [1] TRUE

9999999999999998800000000
#> [1]  9999999999999998758486016
```

While an explanation would be appreciated, I have a practical issue. I'd like to design a faithful `dput()` equivalent that would work with any number.

The constraint to satisfy is : `x == as.numeric(my_deparser(x))`

If `mydeparser()` could return "9999999999999998800000000" for the above for instance I'd be happy, because

```
10000000000000000000000000 == as.numeric("9999999999999998800000000")
#> [1] TRUE
```

I've tried `format()`, `dput()`, `deparse()` with no luck.

How can I achieve this ?

My session info :

R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: How about `my_deparser <- function(x) sprintf("%a", x)`? The string it prints out is hexidemcial so it doesn't look like the original number, but it seems to match back to the number.

Comment: If you use `dput(x, control = "exact")` you should get code that parses to the input for numerics.  It will use the "%a" format where appropriate.

Comment: Re “While an explanation would be appreciated”: I am not familiar with R, but this looks like a bug in the code that converts decimal numerals to floating-point. The closest IEEE-754 binary64 number to 10000000000000000000000000 is 10000000000000000905969664, and that is considerably closer than 9999999999999998758486016 is. So unless rounding down has been requested, I would expect the parsing to yield 10000000000000000905969664. That defect could also explain why parsing `9999999999999998758486016` yields 9999999999999996611002368.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, I'm inclined to call it a bug as well, however `10000000000000000000000000 == 10000000000000000905969664`returns `FALSE`
. The maximum "equal" number seems to be `10000000000000000899999999`

Comment: @MrFlick and user2554330 thanks, that's a workaround that might work, not very pretty but might save the day for these corner cases.

Comment: I went through the trouble of recomputing what would be the decimal value for `sprintf("%a", 10000000000000000000000000)`, and surprise, it's `9999999999999998758486016`, the value that didn't work in the first place :s

Comment: @moodymudskipper: How did you compute that? The two binary64 numbers nearest 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 (10^25) are 9,999,999,999,999,998,758,486,016 and 10,000,000,000,000,000,905,969,664. The distance from the former to 10^25 is 1,241,513,984. The distance from the latter to 10^25 is 905,969,664. Therefore the latter is closer, and it ought to be chosen when 10^25 is converted to a binary64 number.

Comment: Also `10000000000000000000000000` and  `1e25` are different

Comment: @Eric `sprintf("%a", 10000000000000000000000000)`" gives me "0x1.08b2a2c28029p+83", I compute `2^(83 - 4*12)` as a multiplier to `0x108b2a2c28029` (without the dot). The latter is `0x2c28029` + `0x108b2a * 16^7`, I convert hex to dec from there and implemented addition and multiplication high school style not to be limited by the system

Comment: putting everything together I get the cursed number.

Comment: @moodymudskipper: "0x1.08b2a2c28029p+83" is a wrong result for `sprintf("%a", 10000000000000000000000000)`. It should be “0x1.08b2a2c280291p+83”—that is what we get if we do the math correctly, not relying on some potentially deficient software to do it. Getting "0x1.08b2a2c28029p+83" is symptomatic of the problem as I diagnosed it: a bug in the code that converts decimal numerals to floating-point. I have shown you the two binary64 numbers closed to 10^25, and it is clear which one ought to be the result.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Interestingly `10000000000000000000000000 == as.numeric("0x1.08b2a2c28029p+83")` and `10000000000000000000000000 == 0x1.08b2a2c28029p+83` are `TRUE`. I reported the issue to the r-devel mailing list and it also appears results vary with the system. I'll come back here with an answer once it gets sorted out.

Comment: Please don't cross post here and on r-devel.

Comment: Worth updating with results of `sessionInfo()`, especially OS and R version, since people on r-devel are reporting inability to reproduce this under Windows or Linux ... ??

Comment: FWIW I think it's OK to cross-post to r-devel (since it wasn't an immediate spam-across-platforms: in my reading it's essentially escalating what seems to be a bug or serious cross-platform inconsistency to `r-devel`), but it would have been nice to provide the link here (i.e., not to cryptically cross-post)

Comment: It seems the next step would be to write a short bit of C++ code that goes directly to the system-level utilities (i.e. using `printf`/`sprintf`), test across platforms and compiler switches, and see if the problem indeed occurs at the system level rather than within R (which seems likely?)

Comment: @Dirk it's not really cross posting, I posted as an issue here and as I felt we established it to be a bug I reported in r-devel as the next logical step. + there is a practical question that I'd like to solve and that I haven't asked on r-devel : how do I work around this

Comment: All additional info helps. If you feel you must cross post, include at least a link to the earlier discussion. Otherwise you are asking volunteers to turn the same stones over and over which is neither fair nor efficient.

Comment: Yes the link wouldn't have hurt, point taken.

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use a package like [`gmp`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=gmp) or [`Rmpfr`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rmpfr). Below a few examples with package `gmp`.

```r
library(gmp)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gmp'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     %*%, apply, crossprod, matrix, tcrossprod

x <- as.bigz("10000000000000000000000000")
x
#> Big Integer ('bigz') :
#> [1] 10000000000000000000000000

x + 1
#> Big Integer ('bigz') :
#> [1] 10000000000000000000000001
x * x
#> Big Integer ('bigz') :
#> [1] 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question, I don't have 100.....00 stored as a string anywhere, it could be any big number resulting from an obscure operation, and I want to be able to deparse it and reparse it, recovering its value

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MrFlick's comment here's a workaround :

```r
my_deparser <- function(x) {
  x_chr <- format(x, digits = 22)
  if (as.numeric(x_chr) == x) x_chr else sprintf("%a", x)
}

# printed fine already, se we can deparse pretty
x <- 20000000000000000000000000
my_deparser(x)
#> [1] "19999999999999997516972032"
as.numeric(my_deparser(x)) == x
#> [1] TRUE

# need workaround
x <- 10000000000000000000000000
my_deparser(x)
#> [1] "0x1.08b2a2c28029p+83"
as.numeric(my_deparser(x)) == x
#> [1] TRUE
```

That's not ideal since I'd rather print a readable number. I have explored some convoluted solutions computing the `log10(abs(x - x_printed))` and changing digits of `x_printed` (`"9999999999999998758486016"`) to check if the equality is verified, for instance changing the "7" to an "8" below :

```
9999999999999998858486016 == 10000000000000000000000000
#> [1] TRUE
```

This is silly but this can probably give a robust solution with some iterations, very inefficient however.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the `scipen` option has to do with how values are printed, not how they are stored, so when you do:

```
x <- 10000000000000000000000000
```

The value is actually stored as 10000000000000000000000000, even if it prints as something else. So

```
x == 10000000000000000000000000
```

should return TRUE.

Comment: It's true that scipen effects how values are printed, bit the limits of floating point math limit how the numbers are stored in memory. And there's not really anything you can do about that. The number 10000000000000000000000000 cannot be perfectly stored as a floating point number in memory. If you need all those digits you'd need to store as a string or something.

Comment: @MrFlick are you saying that the above code shouldn't work - because it does. Could there be a 32 bit vs 64 bit version difference?

Comment: I'm not saying the above shouldn't work, but it this also works: `x == 10000000000000000000000009`. The number you type into R is not exactly stored in memory. R can't store that number exactly. It stores a number that's close enough in base 2. When you said "value is **actually** stored as ...", that's the part that I don't think is true.